# How to call / run a jQuery nested template recursively

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, recursion, jquery-templates

Ok this is a little like inception for json objects and jquery templating... I want to know how to go deeper. The problem is that i am lazy and want the code to do the work for me....

> **Q:**> How do you call a jQuery template recursively.

Take this json object:

```
var Links =
[{"Name":"Home","NiceUrl":"/home/","Children":null},
 {"Name":"MX-8","NiceUrl":"/mx-8/","Children":null},
 {"Name":"Quiz","NiceUrl":"/quiz/","Children":
      [{"Name":"Thank you","NiceUrl":"/quiz/thank-you/","Children":
         [{"Name":"Can't get here","NiceUrl":"/URL/","Children":null}]
     }]
 }];
```

I can easily get to "Quiz" and its child "Thankyou" using the following template:

```
<script id="itemTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <li><a href="${NiceUrl}">${Name}</a>
        {{tmpl($data) "#childTemplate"}}
    </li>
</script>
<script id="childTemplate" type="text/html">
    <ul>{{each Children}}<li><a href="${NiceUrl}">${Name}</a></li>{{/each}}</ul>
</script>
```

also used is the html and the call to replace it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#itemTemplate").tmpl(Links).appendTo("#SiteMapHolder");
</script>
<ul id="SiteMapHolder">
    <%--jQuery Template will replace this empty space--%>
</ul>
```

I have tried setting the type of the second template to "text/x-jquery-tmpl" and calling a 3rd template but the data being passed seems to be the same as the parent that is calling it.

**so to all beings of higher intelligence and experience then i**, show me the way to be lazy and call a  jQuery template recursively?

PS:sorry this is not in jsFiddle. it doesn't like my script tags. :(

Comment: does any mod know how to make this colourfull so it is easier to read?

Comment: Way before "Inception" had introduced the concept of nested virtual machines to the masses, a coworker/friend of mine decided to try programming while on a variety of different drugs (it was the 70's).  He did acid, and he never got much programming done after it took effect.  He said he looked at a recursive definition of some function and just started laughing.  Then he laughed at the fact that he was laughing.  ...

Comment: @mike i am laughing at myself laughing at this. vicious cycle when will it end !!

Comment: without a base case, the top of the stack's the limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need to check if Children exists and make a recursive call to the same item template with the Children as the data. You would conditionally also add the ul tag. See this jsfiddle for what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/bernardchen1/SK2c6/.

The template itself that I used looks like this:

```
<script id="itemTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
<li><a href="${NiceUrl}">${Name}</a>
    {{if Children}}
    <ul>
    {{tmpl(Children) "#itemTemplate"}}
    </ul>
    {{/if}}
</li>
```

Comment: do you have any code examples that could get me started in the right direction?

Comment: You may have added your comment while I was editing my answer. I have not included a jsfiddle that I believe does what you want, and I have also included the template that I think you need.

Comment: awesome thanks heaps. Its really simple now that i can see it. it can call itself. I was just making a mess of it. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. My comment should have said "now" rather than "not" when I said "not included a jsfiddle".